# Can't render data from api call from one component to another in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, api, angular8

I am new to Angular and I am facing issue in rendering data in UI from an api call. I want to show the data received as response in the parent and show it in a component called `webex-uptime-chart`.

The file with API call is as shown below:

```
public uptimeChartConfig: Array<{ [key: string]: string | any }>;

 this.uptimeChartConfig = [
        {
            rpcMethod: 'getNodeStatus',
            node: this.NodeId,
            duration: '10 mins' 
          },
       ];


// API call to get the Uptime Chart data

          this.uptimeChartConfig
          .filter(config => config.rpcMethod)
          .map(config => {
            return this.rpcService
              .invoke({
                method: 'getNodeStatus',
                args: ['2d945891-be9b-46a8-973e-3f343a8999ad'],
              })
              .then((data: any) => {
                if (data && data.response) {
                  const labels: Array<string> = data.response.map(value =>
                    this.datePipe.transform(value.epochtime * 1000, 'shortTime')
                  );
                  const nodeList = {};
                  data.response.forEach(node => {
                    if (nodeList[node.nodeId]) {
                      nodeList[node.nodeId] = [...nodeList[node.nodeId], node.uptime];
                    } else {
                      nodeList[node.nodeId] = [node.uptime];
                    }
                  });
                  this.lineChartData[config.rpcMethod] = {
                    labels: labels,
                    dataSets: nodeList,
                  };
                } else {
                  this.lineChartData[config.rpcMethod] = {
                    lables: [],
                    dataSets: [],
                  };
                }
              });
```

The response looks as shown below:
[image]

The parent component's html where the `webex-uptime-chart` is called looks as shown below:

```
 <webex-uptime-chart 
  *ngFor="let config of uptimeChartConfig"
  [config]="config"
  [incomingData]="lineChartData[config.rpcMethod]"> 
</webex-uptime-chart>
```

The `webex-uptime-chart.ts` component file is:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'webex-uptime-chart',
  templateUrl: './uptime-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uptime-chart.component.scss']
})
export class UptimeChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() chartData: any[];
  @Input() public config;
  @Input() public incomingData: any;
  public labels: Array<string> = [];
  public dataSets: any = {};
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.labels = this.incomingData.labels;
    this.dataSets = this.incomingData.dataSets;
  }

}
```

The `webex-uptime-chart.html` file is:

```
<div class="uptime-container">
  <ul *ngFor="let data of chartData">
    <li [ngClass]="data.status === 'down' ? 'my-class red-circle' : 'my-class green-circle '">
      <span>{{ config.node }}</span>
    </li>
    <p class="right-text">{{ config.duration }}</p>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

I get the below error while trying to run :

[image]

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: it seems that error shows up before `lineChartData` was initialized. Try initializing the variable in the constructor or anywhere `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 0):

`incomingData` is asynchronous. As a result it is initially provided as undefined to the child component until the promise then callback was executed. But this change is not registered within child component, since you only read `incomingData` within `ngOnInit`.

You could use `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['incomingData'] && !!changes['incomingData'].previousValue) {
    this.labels = changes['incomingData'].currentValue.labels;
    this.dataSets = changes['incomingData'].currentValue.dataSets;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am still not able to render the data in the `webex-uptime-chart` component. Can you please help me with that. I am not sure how to assign the values from the api response.